# not getting json content

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a json string content,

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "Fort Craig Elementary",
"principal": "Michelle Thorne"
}]
```

and I'm writing very simple asp.net Web API method to get above json,

```
[Route("api/schools")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var json = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/data/schools.json");
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;
    }
```

while I m hitting URL "http://localhost:7602/api/schools", it's give me path of json instead json content,

```
c:\users\ajmal\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\Route\Route\data\schools.json
```

Please suggest how to get json content.

Thanks,

Comment: read the file and then set the content to response content

Comment: `MapPath` is just a path building utility. It doesn't magically download that file's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its doing exactly what you have put in the code. Import System.IO  and use the stream reader to read the file. Your `var json` should actually be `var path` to make more sense.

```
 using (var sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
            var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
```